QField Picture naming doesn't work
I have two layers:

Parent layer "Layer1" with the attributes "ID Quelle" and "uuid"
Non-geometry "layer2" for pictures, which has the attributes "path", "parent_uuid" and "subject".

I did a relation between the both layers with layer 1 as parent, referenced field = uuid and Referencing layer = layer 2, referencing field = parent_uuid
For the attribute "parent_uuid" in Layer 2 I put widget type "value relation" with layer = layer 1, key column = uuid, value column = ID Quelle
I want the pictures to be named like that "date_ID Quelle_subject.jpg" But it always uses the default names for the attachment instead of the ID I want.
My attachment naming is the following:
'DCIM/' || format_date(now(), 'yyyyMMddhhmmsszzz')||''||  "parent_uuid" ||''||'subject'||'.jpg'
Edit: I don't know why, but somehow '' is not correctly depicted in the attachment naming on this website. Instead of '' it should read as '__'.
How do I fix this? When I put the attribute "parent_uuid" into the form for taking the picture the correct "ID Quelle" appears.
